# Web page Not Scroll on mobile using java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, mobile-automation

I try to scroll  two pages of website on mobile but one page is working fine but 2nd page is not scroll on mobile. Both pages working fine on window. Please suggest me how to scroll 2nd page. Below is my code for scrolling.

here is link page that not scroll
https://catevolution.com.au/litter-robot-3-connect.html
video link of runnig test on browserstack
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A2R2s8pxO5H3E0lQdUjWEXk5HVtSaXtt/view?usp=sharing

```
      driver.navigate().to("https://catevolution.com.au/index.php?route=common/amp_home");
        System.out.println("Browser is launched");
        System.out.println("Title " + driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Url is launched");

        System.out.println("****************Scrolled down starts****************");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            JavascriptExecutor ja = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            ja.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,350)", "");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("Scrolled time: " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("****************Scrolled down end****************");
        
        System.out.println("****************Scrolled up starts****************");
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            JavascriptExecutor jb = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            jb.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-350)", "");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("Scrolled time: -" + i);
        }
        
        System.out.println("****************Scrolled up end****************");
        
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement hamburgerMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=\"menu-button amp-close-image\"]"));
        hamburgerMenu.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("We have clicked on hamburger menu");

        WebElement subMenuLitterRobot = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Litter-Robot Connect')]"));
        subMenuLitterRobot.click();
        System.out.println("We have clicked on Litter-Robot Connect sub menu");
        
        WebElement writeReview = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Write a review')])[2]"));
        writeReview.isDisplayed();
        writeReview.isEnabled();

        System.out.println("Write review is enable and displayed.");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
        System.out.println("****************Scrolled down starts****************");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
```

/code working fine till there.

```
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
              JavascriptExecutor jaa = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
              jaa.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,350)", "");
              Thread.sleep(500);
              System.out.println("Scrolled time: "+i);
        }
        System.out.println("****************Scrolled down end****************");
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile and windows screen will have different size ,

I checked the page and it seems the height is larger in mobile screen try using

```
jaa.executeScript("document.body.scrollBy(0,350);", "");
```

Comment: We have tested with 350px height as well, but getting the same result scroll is not working, could you please explain why i am facing this issue?

Comment: @Zaman10 window.scrollBy(0,10000000000000) what happens when you give something huge like this ?

Comment: if that works use window.scrollBy(0,document.body.clientHeight)

Comment: Getting same result scroll is not working. Can you please check webpage. If something is different in page like tags or slider create problem. https://catevolution.com.au/litter-robot-3-connect.html

Comment: @Zaman10 added the updated answer find the footer copy right and scroll into that element instead .

Comment: Thanks for your effort. @PDHide I try this method already but I want to scroll page like first page. Please watch the video:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A2R2s8pxO5H3E0lQdUjWEXk5HVtSaXtt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That page had some issue it has an overlay element which cannot be closed

Comment: @Zaman10 updated the answer "document.body.scrollBy(0,350); is working

Comment: Its Working fine.